# How does Fallout handle modded savegames after removing the mod?

Tags: mods, fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

If you add mods to your Fallout game and after some playing time remove the mod (deleting it from data folder), then play the game some more, will your save file still consist the progression of the mod?

I'm mainly concerned with mods that add quests. Basically, when I re-install mod later will I be able to continue from my previous progress through the mod's story?

Comment: By "mods" do you mean official downloadable content or third-party/fan mods?

Comment: Third party mods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I installed Fallout again to try this out, and it seems that when you save your game, mods that are not present at the time of save (even if they were active at some point before) are erased. So reactivating mods later wont work.